# Scrollmagic with Gatsby js and window undefined upon deploy

Tags: javascript, webpack, gatsby, scrollmagic

My Gatsby site can't be deployed to Netlify because of a `WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined`

I've tried:

1. Wrapping return statements in `if(window !== undefined)` checks which didn't work
2. Putting a require statement in my index.js: `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
   require('scrollmagic')
   require('scrollmagic-plugin-gsap')
   }` which didn't work

I noticed that the import statement `import Scrollmagic from 'scrollmagic'` already causes the error because I once tried deploying the site without any scrollmagic code except for the import.

The scrollmagic part of my component looks like this (I deleted some irrelevant variable assignments in this example):

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import ScrollMagic from "scrollmagic"
import { TweenMax, TimelineMax, Power3, TweenLite, TimelineLite } from "gsap"
import { ScrollMagicPluginGsap } from "scrollmagic-plugin-gsap";

const Techstack = () => {
  ScrollMagicPluginGsap(ScrollMagic, TweenMax, TimelineMax);

  const techs = useRef()
  const trigger = useRef()


  useEffect(() => {
    let controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller()
    const techitems = techs.current.children
    const tl = new TimelineMax
    for (let i = 0; i < techitems.length; i++) {
      new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: techitems[i],
      })
        .setTween(TweenLite.from(techitems[i], 1, { opacity: 0, x: -300, ease: Power3.easeOut }))
        .addTo(controller)
    }
  }, [])


    return (
      <TechstackContainer ref={trigger} id="trigger">
        <ContentWrapper ref={techs}>
          <StyledTechstackText>
            Ich baue Webseiten und Apps, am liebsten mit:
        </StyledTechstackText>
          {stack.map(el => {
            return <TechItem>{el}</TechItem>
          })}
        </ContentWrapper>
      </TechstackContainer>
    )
}
```

How would I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see where do you call `window` on your code but the way to solve this all issues is to delay the `window` call after the component is rendered using a `componentDidMount` (in class-based component) or `useEffect` with empty deps (`[]`) in stateless-based component. So, you need to do something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof window !== undefined){
      let controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller()
      const techitems = techs.current.children
      const tl = new TimelineMax
      for (let i = 0; i < techitems.length; i++) {
        new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerElement: techitems[I],
        })
          .setTween(TweenLite.from(techitems[i], 1, { opacity: 0, x: -300, ease: Power3.easeOut }))
          .addTo(controller)
      }
    }
  }, [])
```

*Note the `typeof window !== undefined` condition.*

However, if you are using third-party libraries that uses the window to do their stuff, you will need to put this snippet in your `gatsby-node`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, loaders, getConfig, stage }) => {
  const config = getConfig();

  config.module.rules = [
    // Omit the default rule where test === '\.jsx?$'
    ...config.module.rules.filter(
      rule => String(rule.test) !== String(/\.jsx?$/)
    ),

    // Recreate it with custom exclude filter
    {
      ...loaders.js(),

      test: /\.jsx?$/,

      // Exclude all node_modules from transpilation, except for 'swiper' and 'dom7'
      exclude: modulePath =>
        /node_modules/.test(modulePath)
    },
  ];

  if (stage.startsWith('develop') && config.resolve) {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
    }
  }
};
```

According to Gatsby documentation:

> One solution is to customize your webpack configuration to replace the
>   offending module with a dummy module during server rendering.

Source: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/#fixing-third-party-modules

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. 

The `window` bit is being executed by Scrollmagic in the node modules. On the respective line in the ScrollMagic.js there is this lonely line which causes the problems: window.addEventListener("mousewheel", function () { });

I don't know how to deal with that however. I tried wrapping this in an if check as well, but the deploy failed nonetheless

Comment: Oh, that changes everything @flooz . Sorry to misunderstand. I've edited my answer considering this. :)

Comment: Thanks so much again. This snippet alone didn't work so far and I tried everything to specify the correct path to the Scrollmagic module. It's at least a good hint what to check for next, so thanks again for this. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Cheers, I am getting a different error now. Which is good! It's finally resolved the first one and now I can start working on the next error I guess. Thanks again for your patience!